# How to create activation link after sign up?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web

I am using Spring mvc It does not matter..

I have a sign up section.
Now `My requirement is, After fullfill signup, I want to create an activation link and send it to the user by mail..`

For send mail I am follwing [this code](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-sending-e-mail-via-gmail-smtp-server-with-mailsender/)
Now please can any one tell me how to create activation link.

Comment: Of the many examples available via G! search, this was one of the firsts: http://www.baeldung.com/registration-verify-user-by-email

Comment: I have tried this one..But there are so many errors are coming..thats why I asked abut the idea/any site link

Comment: http://yourapp.com/AServlet?activate=generatedHashUniqueForEveryUser
you can rely hash generation on user's credentials (his mail and login)

in any case it requires addidional column in db to control if account is activated or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
 1.  use of a second table, called pending.

It's basically an 'extension' of the users table, or a copy of the main data, depending on your structure.

2.then generate activation key.
3.send it to user.
4.create a page which will check the key when use click on that link.
```

I think that is okey for you..